# how to get text from listview on clicking that item

Tags: android, listview

This code gives error on clicking Listview

```
 listv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(Display_List.this, "myPos "+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String name = (String) (listv.getItemAtPosition(i));      
            Toast.makeText(Display_List.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: change `Display_List.this` to `getApplicationContext()` in `Toast` and try again

Comment: Could you include your stacktrace too ?

Comment: I changed Display_List.this to getApplicationContext() in Toast. I get no error while running this code,but the "name" is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you are using **below code** so **put it in try catch and check** for below options :-

> (listv.getItemAtPosition(i)

Returns the **item at** your position so there could be **2** reasons

1.) make sure you are having any item at that position and it is not returning null

2.) make sure your item at given position is giving you string object

**EDIT**:-

Use **below code** and also let me  know and if it is still not working ,**after** not working give me your array initialization code

```
String name = String.valueOf((listv.getItemAtPosition(i)));
```

Comment: i am getting positions correct but while trying to get the text from that position,error occurs

Comment: @Aswin.A.S think for second option

Comment: @Aswin.A.S i guess we could better understand your problem if you give us your adapter code also what you are using as list for your listview in adapter so please share your adapter code

Comment: public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  arg1 = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.support,
    null);// insert xml page to listview
  tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_for_lv);
  tv.setText(lis.get(arg0));
  System.out.print(arg0);
  return arg1;
 }

Comment: public void search(View v) {
  cu=dh.get(view_name.getText().toString());
  cu.moveToFirst();
  if (cu.moveToFirst() == true) {
   do {
    li.add(cu.getString(1));
   } while (cu.moveToNext());
  } else
   Toast.makeText(Display_List.this, "No Items with this name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Adaptor ad = new Adaptor(Display_List.this, li);
  listv.setAdapter(ad);

Comment: put debug and check at your click event that you are sure having item at that position it is not giving null?? you sure for that?

Comment: @Aswin.A.S YOU ARE  welcome and you were not properly converting your object to the string :)

Comment: @Aswin.A.S if it helped you, then i guess your responsibility for vote up the answer right? :)